# Change Data Capture in Teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata, cdc

I want to capture INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE activities that are applied to a Teradata table; Something similar to how it works in SQL Server.

I went through the Teradata docs and it seems it does not have built-in support for this feature.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

Your research is correct. Unlike some other databases, Teradata does not externalize a transaction log (that might be mined for change data capture).

You may be able to define triggers to capture change activity and log it to another table or tables.

Answer (score 1):

As Fred said, there is intentionally no CDC on Teradata RDBMS. Depending on what you want to achieve, TEMPORAL with TRANSACTION TIME will be the solution. With this you can answer the question about all DML between two dates or since a specific date (as well Timestamp).